# Keep button in fixed position independent of window size

Tags: html, css

I have a page where a Submit button is supposed to be positioned on the right side of the bar as shown in the picture here: [image: bar position fixed] 
However, I want the button to stay there even when the bar gets scrolled horizontally, which I have achieved via `position: fixed;`. This works until the screen size is adjusted to larger than the window, as seen here: https://media.giphy.com/media/SiErhserLwSYciEdS3/giphy.gif To fix that, I saw some recommendations for making `position: absolute;` which works for the screen size adjustments, but does not leave the button in a fixed position, as evidenced here: https://media.giphy.com/media/wHeXCgQ3fEIlPv2tr4/giphy.gif

My question is how I can achieve this expected result, where the button is fixed to the right side of the table toolbar, unaffected by horizontal scrolling, but is not affected by the window/screen size increasing/decreasing.

The code for this element looks as follows:

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>


.one {
    width: 70%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.two {
    height: 49px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.btn-danger {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was achieved by changing the CSS to `.btn-danger` to:

```
.btn-danger {
    position: sticky;
    margin-top: 7px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

It is acceptable that the button stay on the left in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use bootstrap responsive @media query to create breakpoints like so

> @media (min-width: 576px) { ... } // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) @media (min-width: 768px) { ... } // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) @media (min-width: 992px) { ... } // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }